# How to access database through php with a laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio

So I am working on a website with a laravel framework and using postman to test my code, I am writing code in php and am not able to get specific values from the database table in my code.

I've tried variations of select, where and other functions like `pluck()` and `get()` yet I keep getting an error. I am unsure on how to put it in an array or get it out of an array.

I've tried:

```
$passwordResult = DB::table('users')->where('userName', $userName)->get('password')->toArray();
$passwordResult = DB::table('users')->where('userName', $userName)->value('password');
$passwordResult = DB::table('users')->pluck('password');
```

I want return any value and see it in postman so I can start working on getting specific values. The error I get was that

> "Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as array"

Comment: As @Jasmel Singh suggested `$passwordResult = DB::table('users')->where('userName', $userName)->get(['password'])->toArray();` should work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, are there any reasons why it wouldn't? I am running the server and have postman connected, I am still unable to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this may be helpful for you. Because toArray() function is used with collection

```
 $passwordResult = DB::table('users')->where('userName', $userName)->get('password');
 $passwordResult = $passwordResult->pluck('password')->toArray();
```

Comment: I tried that and I am getting the error that the argument passed must be of type array() and type string() is given.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this

```
$passwordResult = DB::table('users')->where('userName', $userName)->select('password')->get();
$passwordResult = DB::table('users')->where('userName', $userName)->pluck('password')->toArray();
```

Comment: sorry that doesn't work, could it be my mysql database? I'm still trying to figure it out and I can't seem to find the solution